# Get users list by published post count in last month ago

Tags: wordpress

I want get lists of users by published posts count in a month ago.
I have this code but dosnt work, just show registered users in a month ago

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'post_count',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'role'       => 'Subscriber',
    'number'     => '4',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => '12 hours ago',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code
Change query array to this

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '1 month ago'
        )
    )
);
$post_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
```

then in a loop use the_author() function to show your users lists by published post count

```
if ($post_query->have_posts()) {
   while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
     $post_query->the_post();
     the_author();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are trying to do two types of query in one go.
Remember that this query is for users - the date_query is applied to user query and not posts.

[image]

You need to retrieve authors with posts first and then based on their ID you can retrieve their posts with post query.

I think this should look something like this (not tested and please correct me if wrong):

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'post_count',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'role'       => 'Subscriber'
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$authors = $user_query->get_results();

if (!empty($authors)) {
    foreach ($authors as $author){
        $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID); //user data
        $author_id = $author->ID;

        $args = array(
          'author'        =>  $author_id,
          'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
          'order'         =>  'DESC',
          'posts_per_page' => 10,
          'date_query' => array(
                 array(
                      'after' => '1 week ago'
                  )
            )
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

        //post loop here
    }
}
```

The above code should get all Subscribers and retrieve their ID's, for each user there is another query based on their ID to retrieve their posts.

Source 1: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109710/get-posts-get-all-posts-by-author-id
Source 2: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/
Source 3: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99265/display-posts-of-the-last-7-days